# Splitting a list in equal sized chunks in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I want to split:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

into:

```
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]
```

It generally works great with:

```
[ lists:sublist(List, X, 2) || X <- lists:seq(1,length(List),2) ] .
```

But it is really slow this way. 10000 Elements take amazing 2.5 seconds on my netbook. I have also written a really fast recursive function, but I am simply interested: Could this list comprehension also be written in a different way, so that it is faster?

Comment: just note: your solution with list comprehension works so slow because `lists:sublist/3` runtime complexity is O(n), so the overall algorithm complexity is O(n^2)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
part(List) ->
        part(List, []).
part([], Acc) ->
        lists:reverse(Acc);
part([H], Acc) ->
        lists:reverse([[H]|Acc]);
part([H1,H2|T], Acc) ->
        part(T, [[H1,H2]|Acc]).
```

Test in erlang-shell (I've declared this function in module `part`):

```
2> part:part([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]).
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]
3> 
3> timer:tc(part, part, [lists:seq(1,10000)]).
{774,
 [[1,2],
  [3,4],
  [5,6],
  [7,8],
  "\t\n","\v\f",
  [13,14],
  [15,16],
  [17,18],
  [19,20],
  [21,22],
  [23,24],
  [25,26],
  [27,28],
  [29,30],
  [31,32],
  "!\"","#$","%&","'(",")*","+,","-.","/0","12","34",
  [...]|...]}
```

**Just 774 microseconds (which is ~0,8 milliseconds)**

Comment: Fastest solution in my tests.

Comment: It took 40 months, but, mate, finally, you deserved these 10 points! ;)

Comment: Thanks, @marcus! :-)

Answer (score 8):

Here are two quick solutions for you that are both flexible. One is easy to read, but only slightly faster than your proposed solution. The other is quite fast, but is a bit cryptic to read. And note that both of my proposed algorithms will work for lists of anything, not just numeric ordered lists.

Here is the "easy-to-read" one. Call by `n_length_chunks(List,Chunksize)`. For example, to get a list of chunks 2 long, call `n_length_chunks(List,2)`. This works for chunks of any size, ie, you could call `n_length_chunks(List,4)` to get `[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],...]`

```
n_length_chunks([],_) -> [];
n_length_chunks(List,Len) when Len > length(List) ->
    [List];
n_length_chunks(List,Len) ->
    {Head,Tail} = lists:split(Len,List),
    [Head | n_length_chunks(Tail,Len)].
```

The *much faster one* is here, but is definitely harder to read, and is called in the same way: `n_length_chunks_fast(List,2)` (I've made one change to this compared with the one above, in that it pads the end of the list with `undefined` if the length of the list isn't cleanly divisible by the desired chunk length.

```
n_length_chunks_fast(List,Len) ->
  LeaderLength = case length(List) rem Len of
      0 -> 0;
      N -> Len - N
  end,
  Leader = lists:duplicate(LeaderLength,undefined),
  n_length_chunks_fast(Leader ++ lists:reverse(List),[],0,Len).

n_length_chunks_fast([],Acc,_,_) -> Acc;
n_length_chunks_fast([H|T],Acc,Pos,Max) when Pos==Max ->
    n_length_chunks_fast(T,[[H] | Acc],1,Max);
n_length_chunks_fast([H|T],[HAcc | TAcc],Pos,Max) ->
    n_length_chunks_fast(T,[[H | HAcc] | TAcc],Pos+1,Max);
n_length_chunks_fast([H|T],[],Pos,Max) ->
    n_length_chunks_fast(T,[[H]],Pos+1,Max).
```

Tested on my (really old) laptop:

- Your proposed solution took about 3 seconds.
- My slow-but-readable one was slightly faster and takes about 1.5 seconds (still quite slow)
- My fast version takes about 5 milliseconds.
- For completeness, Isac's solution took about 180 milliseconds on my same machine.

Edit: wow, I need to read the complete question first. Oh well I'll keep here for posterity if it helps. As far as I can tell, there's not a good way to do this using list comprehensions. Your original version is slow because each iteration of `sublist` needs to traverse the list each time to get to each successive `X`, resulting in complexity just under O(N^2).

Comment: Ja, I know that and why it is slow. Just wanted to know whether a nice list comprehension could be written doing the job. But still, thanks. Now I at least know that I understood Erlang's basics.

Comment: I would change `n_length_chunks(List,Len) when Len > length(List) -> List;` to `n_length_chunks(List,Len) when Len > length(List) -> [List];`.

Answer (score 3):

Or with a fold:

```
  lists:foldr(fun(E, []) -> [[E]]; 
                 (E, [H|RAcc]) when length(H) < 2 -> [[E|H]|RAcc] ;
                 (E, [H|RAcc]) -> [[E],H|RAcc]
              end, [], List).
```

Comment: I haven't tested it yet, but it looks like great example for foldr in my opinion! (Maybe not what should be done, but what is possible...) I didn't know this is possible at all. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I want to submit slightly complicated but more flexible (and mostly faster) solution of one proposed by @Tilman

```
split_list(List, Max) ->
    element(1, lists:foldl(fun
        (E, {[Buff|Acc], C}) when C < Max ->
            {[[E|Buff]|Acc], C+1};
        (E, {[Buff|Acc], _}) ->
            {[[E],Buff|Acc], 1};
        (E, {[], _}) ->
            {[[E]], 1}
    end, {[], 0}, List)).
```

so function part can be implemented as

```
part(List) ->
     RevList = split_list(List, 2),
     lists:foldl(fun(E, Acc) ->
         [lists:reverse(E)|Acc]
     end, [], RevList).
```

**update**
I've added reverse in case if you want to preserve order, but as I can see it adds no more than 20% of processing time.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
1> {List1, List2} = lists:partition(fun(X) -> (X rem 2) == 1 end, List).
{[1,3,5|...],[2,4,6|...]}
2> lists:zipwith(fun(X, Y) -> [X, Y] end, List1, List2).
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]|...]
```

This takes ~73 milliseconds with a 10000 elements List on my computer. The original solution takes ~900 miliseconds.

But I would go with the recursive function anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more general answer that works with any sublist size.

```
1> lists:foreach(fun(N) -> io:format("~2.10.0B -> ~w~n",[N, test:partition([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],N)]    ) end, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]).
01 -> [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10]]
02 -> [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]
03 -> [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10]]
04 -> [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[10,9]]
05 -> [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]
06 -> [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[10,9,8,7]]
07 -> [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[10,9,8]]
08 -> [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[10,9]]
09 -> [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[10]]
10 -> [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]
```

And the code to achieve this is stored inside a file called `test.erl`:

```
-module(test).
-compile(export_all).

partition(List, N) ->
    partition(List, 1, N, []).

partition([], _C, _N, Acc) ->
    lists:reverse(Acc) ;

partition([H|T], 1, N, Acc) ->
    partition(T, 2, N, [[H]|Acc]) ;

partition([H|T], C, N, [HAcc|TAcc]) when C < N ->
    partition(T, C+1, N, [[H|HAcc]|TAcc]) ;

partition([H|T], C, N, [HAcc|TAcc]) when C == N ->
    partition(T, 1, N, [lists:reverse([H|HAcc])|TAcc]) ;

partition(L, C, N, Acc) when C > N ->
    partition(L, 1, N, Acc).
```

It could probably be more elegant regarding the special case where C > N. Note that C is the size of the current sublist being constructed. At start, it is 1. And then it increments until it reaches the partition size of N.

We could also use a modified version of @chops code to let the last list contains the remaining items even if its size < N :

```
-module(n_length_chunks_fast).

-export([n_length_chunks_fast/2]).

n_length_chunks_fast(List,Len) ->
    SkipLength = case length(List) rem Len of
        0 -> 0;
        N -> Len - N
    end,
    n_length_chunks_fast(lists:reverse(List),[],SkipLength,Len).

n_length_chunks_fast([],Acc,_Pos,_Max) -> Acc;

n_length_chunks_fast([H|T],Acc,Pos,Max) when Pos==Max ->
    n_length_chunks_fast(T,[[H] | Acc],1,Max);

n_length_chunks_fast([H|T],[HAcc | TAcc],Pos,Max) ->
    n_length_chunks_fast(T,[[H | HAcc] | TAcc],Pos+1,Max);

n_length_chunks_fast([H|T],[],Pos,Max) ->
    n_length_chunks_fast(T,[[H]],Pos+1,Max).
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a partition function which can split a large list to small amount of workers. With lkuty's `partition` you might get that one worker gets almost double work than all the others. If that's not what you want, here is a version which sublist lengths differ by at most 1.

Uses [PropEr](http://proper.softlab.ntua.gr/) for testing.

```
%% @doc Split List into sub-lists so sub-lists lengths differ most by 1.
%% Does not preserve order.
-spec split_many(pos_integer(), [T]) -> [[T]] when T :: term().
split_many(N, List) ->
    PieceLen = length(List) div N,
    lists:reverse(split_many(PieceLen, N, List, [])).

-spec split_many(pos_integer(), pos_integer(), [T], [[T]]) ->
    [[T]] when T :: term().
split_many(PieceLen, N, List, Acc) when length(Acc) < N ->
    {Head, Tail} = lists:split(PieceLen, List),
    split_many(PieceLen, N, Tail, [Head|Acc]);

split_many(_PieceLen, _N, List, Acc) ->
    % Add an Elem to each list in Acc
    {Appendable, LeaveAlone} = lists:split(length(List), Acc),
    Appended = [[Elem|XS] || {Elem, XS} <- lists:zip(List, Appendable)],
    lists:append(Appended, LeaveAlone).
```

Tests:

```
split_many_test_() ->
    [
     ?_assertEqual([[1,2]], elibs_lists:split_many(1, [1,2])),
     ?_assertEqual([[1], [2]], elibs_lists:split_many(2, [1,2])),
     ?_assertEqual([[1], [3,2]], elibs_lists:split_many(2, [1,2,3])),
     ?_assertEqual([[1], [2], [4,3]], elibs_lists:split_many(3, [1,2,3,4])),
     ?_assertEqual([[1,2], [5,3,4]], elibs_lists:split_many(2, [1,2,3,4,5])),
     ?_assert(proper:quickcheck(split_many_proper1())),
     ?_assert(proper:quickcheck(split_many_proper2()))
    ].


%% @doc Verify all elements are preserved, number of groups is correct,
%% all groups have same number of elements (+-1)
split_many_proper1() ->
    ?FORALL({List, Groups},
            {list(), pos_integer()},
            begin
                Split = elibs_lists:split_many(Groups, List),

                % Lengths of sub-lists
                Lengths = lists:usort(lists:map(fun erlang:length/1, Split)),

                length(Split) =:= Groups andalso
                lists:sort(lists:append(Split)) == lists:sort(List) andalso
                length(Lengths) =< 2 andalso
                case Lengths of
                    [Min, Max] -> Max == Min + 1;
                    [_] -> true
                end
            end
           ).

%% @doc If number of groups is divisable by number of elements, ordering must
%% stay the same
split_many_proper2() ->
    ?FORALL({Groups, List},
            ?LET({A, B},
                 {integer(1, 20), integer(1, 10)},
                 {A, vector(A*B, term())}),
            List =:= lists:append(elibs_lists:split_many(Groups, List))
           ).
```

Answer (score -1):

I've slightly altered the implementation from @JLarky to remove the guard expression, which should be slightly faster:

```
split_list(List, Max) ->
    element(1, lists:foldl(fun
        (E, {[Buff|Acc], 1}) ->
            {[[E],Buff|Acc], Max};
        (E, {[Buff|Acc], C}) ->
            {[[E|Buff]|Acc], C-1};
        (E, {[], _}) ->
            {[[E]], Max}
    end, {[], Max}, List)).
```