# Getting the boxes from a Sudoku in Erlang

Tags: list, erlang, sudoku

I am new to Erlang and trying to make a Sudoku solver. So far I can have an input consisting of a list of 81 integers (9x9) like this

```
sudoku() -> [6,7,1,8,2,3,4,9,5,5,4,9,1,7,6,3,2,8,3,2,8,5,4,9,1,6,7,1,3,2,6,5,7,8,4,9,9,8,6,4,1,2,5,7,3,4,5,7,3,9,8,6,1,2,8,9,3,2,6,4,7,5,1,7,1,4,9,3,5,2,8,6,2,6,5,7,8,1,9,3,4].
```

That I split into rows based on the [list splitting algorithm by stemm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534898/splitting-a-list-in-equal-sized-chunks-in-erlang):

```
split_rows(sudoku()).
```

Which returns:

```
  [5,4,9,1,7,6,3,2,8],
  [3,2,8,5,4,9,1,6,7],
  [1,3,2,6,5,7,8,4,9],
  [9,8,6,4,1,2,5,7,3],
  [4,5,7,3,9,8,6,1,2],
  [8,9,3,2,6,4,7,5,1],
  [7,1,4,9,3,5,2,8,6],
  [2,6,5,7,8,1,9,3,4]]
```

To obtain the columns I just transpose this matrix with the [elegant solution of mpm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389254/transposing-a-2-dimensional-matrix-in-erlang).

The next step is to collect lists of the nine square boxes. Then I can check if there are duplicate elements in those lists to see if a solution is valid.

Unfortunately I have no clear idea how to obtains the squares, e.g.,

```
[[1],[2],[3],
[4],[5],[6],
[7],[8],[9]]
```

where each square represents the nine numbers in the block. So square one in this case looks like this:

```
[5,4,9,
3,2,8,
1,2,2]
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`lists:sublist/3`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#sublist-3) for this:

```
square(X, Y, Side, Board) ->
    Rows = lists:sublist(Board, (Y-1)*Side + 1, Side),
    [lists:sublist(Row, (X-1)*Side + 1, Side) || Row <- Rows].
```

It will return list of lists

```
1> Board =
[[6,7,1,8,2,3,4,9,5],
 [5,4,9,1,7,6,3,2,8],
 [3,2,8,5,4,9,1,6,7],
 [1,3,2,6,5,7,8,4,9],
 [9,8,6,4,1,2,5,7,3],
 [4,5,7,3,9,8,6,1,2],
 [8,9,3,2,6,4,7,5,1],
 [7,1,4,9,3,5,2,8,6],
 [2,6,5,7,8,1,9,3,4]].

4> so:square(1,1,3,Board). 
[[6,7,1],
 [5,4,9],
 [3,2,8]]
5> so:square(3,3,3,Board).
[[7,5,1],
 [2,8,6],
 [9,3,4]]
6> so:square(2,2,3,Board).
[[6,5,7],
 [4,1,2],
 [3,9,8]]
7> so:square(3,2,3,Board).
[[8,4,9],
 [5,7,3],
 [6,1,2]]
```

If you want just a list (flat list) use [`lists:flatten/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#flatten-1) on a result of `square/4`.

Comment: I was trying to make a list of tuples by indexing the values and then calculate the square number, but this is better! The indexes are still useful. Thanks!

Comment: It's [`list comprehension`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/list_comprehensions.html). `Row <- Rows` means for every `Row` in `Rows`.

Comment: Well thanks again for your answer it works like a charm and now I can check sudokus on their validness. Unfortunately I do not know why it works, but I will print it out and look at it on my way home.